# Mapbox always visits driver location twice for the roundtrip

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using this [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/optimization-api/) provided by mapbox for optimization by clicking on the map. However, it always visits the driver's location one more time before getting to the warehouse which is wrong.

The right attitude is definitely:
Driver location->Warehouse->Addresses->Warehouse

However, the app makes this:
Driver location->Warehouse->Addresses->*Driver location*->Warehouse

Here is the responsible part of the example. I don't see what causes such an attitude.

```
return (
          'https://api.mapbox.com/optimized-trips/v1/mapbox/driving/' +
          coordinates.join(';') +
          '?distributions=' +
          distributions.join(';') +
          '&overview=full&steps=true&geometries=geojson&source=first&access_token=' +
          mapboxgl.accessToken
        );
```

I've tried to play with destination=last or any...
Any ideas what should be changed?